# Asymptotic expansion of a convolution integral

Tags: asymptotics, convolution, dirac-delta

Suppose I have a convolution integral
$$\tilde{F}(x; g)=\int dy F(x-y) K(y;g),$$
with a kernel
$$K(x;g)\equiv\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{g}{x^2+g^2}.$$
The result of the integral depends on the parameter $g$ in the kernel, and so we should be able to do an asymptotic expansion in powers of $g$ about $g=0$. Since in the limit $g\rightarrow 0$ the kernel $K$ becomes a Dirac delta function, the lowest order term should just be $F$ itself,
$$\tilde{F}(x; g)=F(x)+\mathcal{O}(g),$$
but how do I get the rest of the asymptotic expansion?

If I naively expand the kernel inside the integral
$$K(x; g) = \frac{g}{\pi x^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{g^2}{x^2}\right)^k$$
then for one thing I miss the lowest order term, and also I run into convergence problems due to the presence of powers of $x^2$ in the denominator. I'm wondering if there is a useful way to do this asymptotic expansion without specifying the form of the function $F$.

Comment: [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) may be of use here.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, Thanks for your comment. I didn't end up seeing a way to use Laplace's method, but it prompted me to think about the problem using integral transforms.

Answer (score 1):

The expansion in $g$ is more well-behaved after a Fourier transform.
$$f(u)\equiv \int dx F(x)e^{iux}$$ $$k(u;g) \equiv \int dx K(x;g)e^{iux}=e^{-g|u|}$$
$$\tilde{F}(x;g)=\int \frac{du}{2\pi}e^{-iux}f(u)e^{-g|x|}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{du}{2\pi}e^{-iux}f(u)\frac{(-g|u|)^k}{k!}$$
The terms involving even powers of $g^k$ are derivatives of delta functions that are missing in the naive expansion in my question, and each term of the expansion converges as long as the Fourier transform $f(u)$ decays sufficiently fast.

Comment: In particular $F$ will have to be infinitely differentiable to satisfy the decay requirements.